# Can't figure out how to print the following outputs

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, printing

I'm printing out lowest tax from my project, but I'm stuck on this problem. How can I change this output:

```
Income: 6100  
Lowest tax: 1540.0  
1540.0  
Norway  
 
Income: 9000  
Lowest tax: 2340.0  
2340.0  
Canada
```

To this:

```
Income: 1000000  
Lowest tax: 150000.0  
USA   
Income: 6000  
Lowest tax: 1500.0  
Denmark Norway USA   
Income: -1
```

Here is my code:

```
continue_input = True
income = 0


while continue_input :
    income = int(input('Income: '))

    
    if income < 0 :
        continue_input = not True

    # Canada   
    canada_tax = 0.26
    canada = canada_tax * income

    # Norway
    if income > 3000:
        norway_tax1 = 0.1 * 3000
        tax_left = income - 3000
        norway_tax2 = 0.4 * tax_left
        norway_tax = norway_tax1 + norway_tax2
    elif income <= 3000:
        norway_tax = 0.1 * income

    # Denmark
    denmark_tax = 0
    percent = 0
    for _ in range(int(income/1000)):
      denmark_tax += percent * 1000
      percent += 0.1
    denmark_tax += percent * (income%1000)
      
    # USA
    if income <= 1500:
        USA_tax = 0.12 * income
    elif income > 1500 and income <= 6000:
        USA_tax = 0.25 * income
    elif income > 6000 and income <= 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.38 * income
    elif income > 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.15 * income
        

    
    min_tax = min(canada, norway_tax, USA_tax, denmark_tax)
    print(f'Lowest tax: {min_tax}')
    print(min_tax)

    if min_tax == canada :
        print('Canada')

    if min_tax == denmark_tax :
        print('Denmark')

    if min_tax == norway_tax :
        print('Norway')

    if min_tax == USA_tax :
        print('USA')
    print()
```

Comment: can you be more precise by inputting same income in obtained and desired output..

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to break out of the while loop immediately if income is < 0, so:

   if income < 0:
   break
2. Delete the line `print(min_tax)`, it's printing min_tax an extra time.
3. To put the country names all on the same line, do the following:

```
    if min_tax == canada :
        print('Canada', end=" ")

    if min_tax == denmark_tax :
        print('Denmark', end=" ")

    if min_tax == norway_tax :
        print('Norway', end=" ")

    if min_tax == USA_tax :
        print('USA', end=" ")

    print()
```

Adding `end=" "` to `print()` will prevent it from adding a newline. It will add a space instead.

Comment: the code should stop after it's input is <0

Comment: @BobbyJackson yes, so I suggested replacing "continue_input = not True" with "break". Break will get out of the while loop immediately.

Comment: okey will do that, but the output is still the same

Comment: @BobbyJackson ok i updated my answer to also put the country names all on the same line